# Node server hangs on Loading dependency graph

Tags: node.js, react-native, genymotion

I just created a new react-native app and when i use react-native start on the folder of my app, it hangs on 'Loading dependency graph...' and then i need to shut it down via Task manager because the process takes all my memory.

I tried to reinstall node, npm, yarn and chocolatey and cleared all the cache.

Comment: have you tried just stopping react-native start process and then call `react-native run-android` or `run-ios` ? Sometimes its not showing output of dependency graph but run command works fine

Comment: @KirankumarDafda yes, when i do this i get the same problem..

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried to downgrade node version from `12.4` to `10.16.0` AND use `react-native start --reset-cache` BUT STILL IN STUCK.

However, I tried `sudo npm start --reset-cache`(NOT `sudo react-native start --reset-cache`), and IT FINALLY WORKED!

Using RN 0.61.5

You gotta be kidding me...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using react-native version "0.55.4" instead of  "0.60.0" !!
`react-native init --version "0.55.4" App01`

Comment: Yes, the stable version for now is '0.55.4' which supports almost all plugins and components

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to downgrade Node from 12.7.0 to 12.4.0. I was able to keep RN at 0.60.4

Answer (score 0):

Using command:

```
lsof -i tcp:8081
kill -9 <pid number>
sudo npm start -- --reset-cache
```